# How do I make emacs-key-bindings work everywhere in linux

Tags: emacs, python, xorg, openbox, xdotools

I am just tired of reaching for the home and arrow keys.
There is a windows hack:
http://www.davesquared.net/2008/02/emacs-key-bindings-everywhere.html
How can we achieve that in linux?
The alternative is to make every textfield editable in a emacs buffer, see this question:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239768/how-to-edit-text-anywhere-with-your-favorite-editor-in-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. There isn't a single class or object that's used to input text in Linux programs. There is on MacOS, but not on Linux.

Comment: Autokey can do some of cursor movement through shortcut, but it doesn't work all the time.